# Acumatica - Add Required Attribute to new Case through Rest API

Tags: json, rest, acumatica

I am trying to create new Acumatica cases through the REST API. There is an attribute on the cases that I am trying to populate. I created a Detail object for the case attributes like this.

[Case Attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQP1e.jpg)

I then tried to populate a test case using the below code.

```
        public async Task CreateTestCase()
    {
        Case newCase = new Case
        {
            ClassID = new JsonObject<string> { value = this.DepartmentToClassID["1"] },
            DateReported = new JsonObject<DateTime> { value = DateTime.Now },
            BusinessAccount = new JsonObject<string> { value = this.UserOrganizationToBusinessAccount["67"] },
            LastActivityDate = new JsonObject<DateTime> { value = DateTime.Now },
            Owner = new JsonObject<string> { value = this.OwnerToEmployee["43"] },
            ClosingDate = new JsonObject<DateTime?> { value = null },
            Severity = new JsonObject<string> { value = this.PriorityToSeverity["1"] },
            Status = new JsonObject<string> { value = this.Status["1"] },
            Subject = new JsonObject<string> { value = "Test Case" },

            Attributes = new List<CaseAttribute>
            {
                new CaseAttribute
                {
                    AttributeID = new JsonObject<string> { value = "Kayako Ticket Number" },
                    Value = new JsonObject<string> { value = "12345" }
                }
            }
        };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newCase);

        try
        {


            var response = await _httpClient.PutAsync("Custom/1.0/Case", new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

            string res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return;
        }
    }
```

JsonObject just adds the { "value": } object that Acumatica requires. Here is the JSON string that results from the above code.

```
{
    "ClassID": {
        "value": "SUPPORT"
    },
    "Contact": null,
    "DateReported": {
        "value": "2017-07-10T00:41:45.045008-07:00"
    },
    "BusinessAccount": {
        "value": "24SEVEN"
    },
    "LastActivityDate": {
        "value": "2017-07-10T00:41:45.045008-07:00"
    },
    "Owner": {
        "value": "JSS"
    },
    "ClosingDate": {
        "value": null
    },
    "Severity": {
        "value": "Medium"
    },
    "Status": {
        "value": "Open"
    },
    "Subject": {
        "value": "Test Case"
    },
    "Attributes": [{
        "AttributeID": {
            "value": "Kayako Ticket Number"
        },
        "Value": {
            "value": "12345"
        }
    }]
}
```

This matches the case object when I run a GET. The response that comes back is "500 Internal Server Error" and there are two errors:

`CR Error: There are empty required attributes: 'Kayako Ticket Number'
Case.Attributes[1].Value: 'Kayako Ticket Number' cannot be empty.`

When I create the attribute, it is created at index 0. The error indicates it is looking at index 1. Is there a way for me to load the attribute based on the attribute string and not the index number? Is it possible the attribute is not even being loaded at all?

I also tried using the KAYAKONUMB_Attributes dynamic field to load the entry. The GET successfully returned the following:

```
"KayakoTicketNumber": {
    "value": "12002"
},
```

The PUT, however, returned the first error above, but not the second one.  My JSON string matched the GET response.

## Update

Following Serg's advice, I extended the default endpoint, and now I am able to load two of the three attributes I have.  The last attribute I am trying to load is a combo box.  It seems like there needs to be a different way to load that particular attribute.

Here is my current endpoint setup:

[image: Case Attributes]

And here is my new object initializer:

```
        Case newCase = new Case
        {
            ClassID = new JsonObject<string> { value = this.DepartmentToClassID["3"] },
            Contact = new JsonObject<int> { value = 22322 },
            DateReported = new JsonObject<DateTime> { value = DateTime.Now },
            BusinessAccount = new JsonObject<string> { value = this.UserOrganizationToBusinessAccount["218"] },
            LastActivityDate = new JsonObject<DateTime> { value = DateTime.Now },
            Owner = new JsonObject<string> { value = this.OwnerToEmployee["43"] },
            ClosingDate = new JsonObject<DateTime?> { value = null },
            Severity = new JsonObject<string> { value = this.PriorityToSeverity["1"] },
            Status = new JsonObject<string> { value = this.Status["1"] },
            Subject = new JsonObject<string> { value = "Test Case" },
            Attributes = new List<CaseAttribute<string>>
            {
                new CaseAttribute<string>
                {
                    AttributeID = new JsonObject<string> { value = "Kayako Ticket Number" },
                    Value = new JsonObject<string> { value = "12345" }
                },
                new CaseAttribute<string>
                {
                    AttributeID = new JsonObject<string> { value = "Case Reply Due Date" },
                    Value = new JsonObject<string> { value = "2010-10-30 00:00:00.000" }
                },
                new CaseAttribute<string>
                {
                    AttributeID = new JsonObject<string> { value = "Upgrade Stage" },
                    Value = new JsonObject<string> { value = "7. Test In Progress"}
                }
            }
        };
```

The error message being returned is:

`PX.Data.PXException: CR Error: There are empty required attributes: 'Upgrade Stage'`

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, attributes are a special case (always). From what I see, you've mapped your own `CaseAttribute` object for this - and, unfortunately, this won't work without special actions. Try using `AttributeValue` entity from Acumatica's `Default` endpoint (and, of course, make sure that your endpoint extends `Default`), that *might* help you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I was only able to find AttributeDefinition which is just the definition of the attributes, but not the values within a particular entity.  I knew they are a special case but am hoping there is a way to still populate them automatically.

Comment: `AttributeValue` is a detail used in, if I'm not mistaken, `StockItem`. I'll be able to check it tomorrow.

Comment: Serg, thank you for your help.  I did see the StockItem entity earlier, and tried using "AttributeValue" as the object name.  It did not work, but I was not extending the default endpoint.  I changed that, and it seems to get me closer.  I am able to load two of the three attributes I have, but the third one is not loading.  I can update my question with more info.  Thanks.

Comment: Serg, I have still been unable to get the attributes loaded that have drop down values.  We moved the fields from attributes into custom fields and I am now able to add those fields.  It is not a solution to my issue, but a workaround for us.  Your point about extending the default endpoint was helpful though, so thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve the issue by creating a linked object and setting the attribute that way.  Here is the endpoint setup (sorry for the linked images, my rep is still too low):

[Linked Entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rviNT.jpg)

And here is the code for creating the case object.  I may need to tweak the endpoint and the objects as currently it is linking to an array of attributes but returning only the first one.  I am hoping there is a way to return individual attributes.

```
        Case newCase = new Case
        {
            ClassID = new JsonObject<string> { value = this.DepartmentToClassID["1"] },
            Contact = new JsonObject<int> { value = 22322 },
            DateReported = new JsonObject<DateTime> { value = DateTime.Now },
            BusinessAccount = new JsonObject<string> { value = this.UserOrganizationToBusinessAccount["218"] },
            LastActivityDate = new JsonObject<DateTime> { value = DateTime.Now },
            Owner = new JsonObject<string> { value = this.OwnerToEmployee["43"] },
            ClosingDate = new JsonObject<DateTime?> { value = null },
            Severity = new JsonObject<string> { value = this.PriorityToSeverity["1"] },
            Status = new JsonObject<string> { value = this.Status["1"] },
            Subject = new JsonObject<string> { value = "Test Case" },
            KayakoTicket = new CaseAttribute
            {
                AttributeID = new JsonObject<string> { value = "Kayako Ticket Number" },
                Value = new JsonObject<int> { value = 12345 }
            }
        };
```

Finally, here is a screenshot of the case in Acumatica.

[Created Case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPjqE.jpg)

Comment: This was not actually a solution since I am unable to add more than one attribute.  Serg's response it getting me closer to what I need but there is still a slight issue.

Comment: I found that having the manual numbering setting turned on in Configuration -> Common Settings -> Common Settings -> Numbering Sequences can cause this error. After hours spent figuring this out, I really wish acumatica provided better error messages. Surely this is just lack of sufficient ID check on the incoming web request. This "REST" API definitely has a long way to go!

Comment: Hi micwallace, I missed your comment for some reason. I have not had a chance to test out this setting as the data was imported another way, but if this issue surfaces again for a different project, I will remember to test this out.  Thank you so much for the help!